# Create a new file in the directory of the open file in vim?

Tags: vim

I find myself in the position where I want to create a new file in the same directory as the one that the open file is in. How do I create a new file in the directory of the open file in vim? Also, is there a a place where I can learn these things on my own? Googling didn't help.

Comment: Are you talking about vim, the text editor on Linux?

Answer (score 263, accepted):

From within Vim, new files are created like existing files are edited, via commands like `:edit filename` or `:split filename`. To persist them to disk, you need to (optionally type in contents and) persist them via `:write`.

Like a command prompt, Vim has a notion of *current directory* (`:pwd` lists it). All file paths are relative to it. You don't need to duplicate the path to your current file, there are some nice shortcuts for them: `%` refers to the current file, `:h` is a modifier for its directory, minus the file name (cp. `:help filename-modifiers`). So,

```
:e %:h/filename
:w
```

will create a new file named `filename` in the same directory as the currently open file, and write it.

Alternatively, some people like Vim to always change to the current file's directory. This can be configured by placing

```
:set autochdir
```

into your `~/.vimrc` file (which is read on Vim startup). Then, above becomes simply

```
:e filename
:w
```

Finally, Vim has a great built-in `:help`. Learn to navigate and search it!

Comment: `autochdir` is flaky, unfortunately, and I found I couldn't depend on it.  Instead I put an autocmd in my vimrc: `autocmd BufEnter  *  silent! lcd %:p:h:gs/ /\\ /`

Comment: Dawg would like to up vote your answer too but Dawg doesn't have the necessary rep. Thanks for the well written explanation!

Answer (score 21):

you should have a try with "nerdtree" plugin.
In the nerdtree window, you typed key m, and file operation choices will display to you

Answer (score 19):

If you want to create a new file and also show it in the window next to your current file, you can try this:

```
:vsp newfile
```

The `vsp` stands for `vertical split`, and it splits the screen in half, one showing your current file, the other showing your new file (also works with just `sp`, which is a horizontal split).

Per @MartinLyne's comment above, this will create the file in the directory of the file in which you opened `vim`. To adjust for this, you can change the current working directory as follows:

```
:cd %:p:h
```

This command changes the current working directory to the directory of the active file, meaning that running the `vsp` command (or any of the commands above) will create the file in that directory.

Answer (score 5):

When you have **opened vim in non existent location** like

`$ vim /etc/<some_folder/<next_folder>/file.cfg`

then to **create a new directory while being inside vim**, just run in normal mode

`:! mkdir -p /etc/<some_folder/<next_folder>`

next save your doc as usual `:w :x ZZ` (whatever you like)

that's it

Answer (score 5):

I usually use:

```
:tabnew my-file
```

Then add some content and:

```
:w
```

It will create new tab for new file.

(I use Vim 8)

Answer (score 3):

I'm quite late to the party, but another option is to open NERDtree with `:E` or `:Explore` (or its splitting alternatives `:Vexplore`/`:Sexplore` == `:Vex`/`:Sex`).

In NerdTree you can create a new file with `%`, and type the name. It will automatically open the file, and create it after you `:w`/save it.

Comment: Yeah i use a remap for opening NerdTree `nnoremap <leader>pv :wincmd v<bar> :Ex <bar> :vertical resize 30<CR>` and `%` was very helpful with it.

Answer (score 2):

This is for Gvim!
Enter this to see the current directory.

```
:cd
```

then change it with

```
:cd desktop/somefolder
```

then save or make new file there

```
:enew asd.cpp
```

now again see the file

```
:cd
```

Answer (score 2):

With `NERDtree`

```sh
 ma <FILENAME>
 ma <DIRECTORY NAME> + /
```

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, you could create a custom command called `:CreateFile` in your vim config as follows:

```
" Command to create file in the opened file's directory
" Takes file_name as argument.
:command -nargs=1 CreateFile edit %:h/<args>
```

**Usage**:

`:Command test.txt` will create `test.txt` in the currently opened file's directory.

Was inspired by @Ingo's answer and this nice [tutorial](https://kaiwern.com/posts/2022/04/28/writing-a-custom-vim-command/) on creating custom commands in vim.